# How can I get my JS errors in chrome to show the correct line numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, debugging

I believe my webpack config may be the culprit or my `npm run dev` script, but I'm not sure what the issue is. When I run my app in dev mode I'm getting error messages like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.contacts.map is not a function
    at ContactList.renderList (ContactList.jsx:46)
    at ContactList.render (ContactList.jsx:61)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14695)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14650)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15598)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19266)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19306)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
```

But my ContactList.jsx is only 36 lines long.

My webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './client/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: { 
              presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
            }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
};
```

scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx webpack --mode=development && node server/server.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode=development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development"
  }
```

One other important detail, I think, is that I'm serving my front-end app via an express server. It is that front-end application I'm trying to debug. Can I package it in a dev mode or something like this?

I'm serving an html and bundle.js file. The HTML just references the endpoint where I'm serving my react application.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Minimal React Webpack Babel Setup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My app is here:

https://github.com/int-a/contacts/tree/split-first-last-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add devtool in webpack config ,like 'devtool:"#source-map"'

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to have worked. Will I have to remove this as a part of productionizing? Would there be any unwanted affects?

Comment: you shouldn't use it in production because it will increase the size of your bundle

Comment: thanks. I found more info about it here also https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ Though they mention here that source-map is good for production, and eval-source-map for dev.